# I can't get the activity name using adb shell

Tags: android, android-activity, adb

I know that many people already sent questions similar to this. However, this is a little different.

I have to try to get the current activity from an android app, but it is not possible. Normally, I interact with the app and execute this: *adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'*. However, it always shows MainActivity. I checked the activity list on APK Info and this list is so little
[image: screen from APK Info]

So, there is some way to start a specific screen of apps similar to this?

Comment: How is your question different than the other questions you found?

Comment: Because I can't see all screens from app by APK Info or add shell. For instance, the app has login page, registration page, etc. But, when I check the current activity by ads shell it always show MainActivity.

Comment: 1. Maybe there's only one activity and each page is displayed by using a fragment. 2. How can there be more than one "current" activity?

Comment: Sounds Great @Code-Apprentice. I believe there's only one activity and each page has a fragment. This way, is it possible call a specific fragment instead of activity?